# Compound query for Parse.com using REST API

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, parse-platform

A project I have inherited currently uses Parse for backend. I am trying to migrate the way the data is fetched/posted, from the Parse iOS SDK to using the Parse REST API (using `AFNetworking`).

I was able to convert a simple `PFQuery` like the following to it's REST equivalent:

**`PFQuery`**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'999Z'"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSString *createdAt = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:createdAtDate];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
[query whereKey:@"createdAt" lessThan:createdAt];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query setLimit:10];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //Etc...
    }
}];
```

**REST API Request**:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'999Z'"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSString *createdAt = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:createdAtDate];

NSString *dateQueryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"createdAt\":{\"$lte\":{\"__type\":\"Date\",\"iso\":\"%@\"}}}", createdAt];

    NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"order": @"-createdAt",
                                 @"limit": @10,
                                 @"include": @"user",
                                 @"where":dateQueryString};    

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer parseSerializer]; // Already has App-Id, App-key and Content-Type set.

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:@"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Photo" parameters:parameters error:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // Etc..

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

[operation start];
```

The problem however is with compound queries like the one below:

```
NSMutableArray* subqueriesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

PFQuery *followingActivitiesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:@“type” equalTo:@“Follow”];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:@“fromUser” equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
followingActivitiesQuery.limit = 1000;

PFQuery *privateUserQuery = [PFUser query];
[privateUserQuery whereKey:@“yourMomLikedThisPhoto” equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]; // fake whereKey of course

PFQuery *photosFromFollowedUsersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
[photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:@“yourMomLikedThisPhoto” equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:@“user” matchesKey:@“toUser” inQuery:followingActivitiesQuery];
[photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:@“user” matchesQuery:privateUserQuery];

PFQuery *photosFromCurrentUserQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
[photosFromCurrentUserQuery whereKey:@“yourMomLikedThisPhoto” equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[photosFromCurrentUserQuery whereKey:@“user” equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

[subqueriesArray addObject:photosFromFollowedUsersQuery];
[subqueriesArray addObject:photosFromCurrentUserQuery];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:subqueriesArray];
[query includeKey:@"Photo"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
```

If someone could help me understand how to construct the `parameters` for this, I'd really appreciate it. A general idea on how to proceed in the right direction will also help. I've referred the [Parse REST API Guide](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries-compound-queries), but I can't seem to get it. I'm trying to get it right using `$inQuery`, but no luck yet.

An answer to this question will cover most of the common and complex issues one faces when querying with the Parse REST API (on iOS).

Comment: Try running the app with Charles monitoring to see exactly what it sends

Comment: You can get all records with normal REST API query and you can apply constrains by Predicates. This may help you to get your solution.

Comment: @AjayGabani, that is fine, but if I wanted to do that, I would have done that earlier. I need to optimise data usage too. What if there are a million record in the database, but only 20 that satisfy my compound query? That won't be good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Transformative use of $or**

I think that what you will want to do is transform the following call into a relevant http call using the library of your choice (AFNetworking). As you can see the subquery behavior is embedded in a specific encoded url that contains an array with dictionary whose values are dictionaries with comparison statements.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"$or":[{"wins":{"$gt":150}},{"wins":{"$lt":5}}]}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Player
```

([source](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries-relational-queries))

Another approach would be use of subclass queries.

**Subclass Queries**

You can get a query for objects of a particular subclass using the class method query. The following example queries for armors that the user can afford:

```
PFQuery *query = [Armor query];
[query whereKey:@"rupees" lessThanOrEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser][@"rupees"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    Armor *firstArmor = [objects firstObject];
    // ...
  }
}];
```

([source](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-compound-queries))

**Relational Queries**

There are several ways to issue queries for relational data. If you want to retrieve objects where a field matches a particular PFObject, you can use whereKey:equalTo: just like for other data types. For example, if each Comment has a Post object in its post field, you can fetch comments for a particular Post:

```
// Assume PFObject *myPost was previously created.
// Using PFQuery
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
[query whereKey:@"post" equalTo:myPost];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    // comments now contains the comments for myPost
}];

// Using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"post = %@", myPost];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment" predicate:predicate];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    // comments now contains the comments for myPost
}];
```

One Parse Blog [Post](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/hello-nspredicate/) also mentions that predicates can be further enhanced using:

> At this time, we support these NSPredicate features:
>
> Simple comparisons such as =, !=, <, >, <=, >=, and BETWEEN with a key
>   and a constant. Containment predicates, such as x IN {1, 2, 3}.
>   Key-existence predicates, such as x IN SELF. BEGINSWITH expressions.
>   Compound predicates with AND, OR, and NOT. Sub-queries with "key IN
>   %@", subquery. See our docs for more details and examples.

**Specific Tips on Decomposing Parameters**

I'd suggest evaluating any samples that show how REST API values are interpreted. Keeping in mind that most transmissions will likely represent a JSON-like format. In these cases '[' square braces are arrays, '{' curly braces represent dictionaries and you will want to encode the parametrized data before pushing it into your http request.

**Applied Information**

Taking what is discussed above, you can create a REST API call. You must encode the where clause of the various criterion specific to your use-case. The following method can be used to ensure those parameters are in line with the query properties you need:

```
var encodedParam = param.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Assuming that param above is some string with your key-values similar to:

```
'where={"$or":[{"wins":{"$gt":150}},{"wins":{"$lt":5}}]}'
```

The encoded parameters would be added after your Application ID and REST API key onto the basic REST-API query string - this should return the objects you want:
[image: api-query] (note the fourth url used for queries).

It looks like the encoded parameters should go after the classname referenced above as in the following example:

[image: encoded-params] (extrapolate your values using the format above, also note the extra characters on the query string  "...classname **?%s** encodedParams").

*Additional query operators you may want to use include:*

[image: query-operators]

*Additional Query Examples*

[image: another-example]

One could extrapolate how to construct more complex queries by using the supplied [examples](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#queries) on the Parse website. Packing these queries into encoded parameters should yield the results you seek. What I would do is first construct a query using the regular Parse API and then convert that to the REST-API construct identified above.

**Eg:**

```
let urlpath = NSString(format: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Photo?%s\(encodedParams)")

... add code to call the urlPath
```

**Specific Answer to Your Main Issue**

After re-reading the question I wanted to reply to your specific problem with needing to add multiple subqueries onto the REST-API parameter list. I think that close inspection of the $or clause would be useful. As long as you can apply related keys on the Photo object into the multiple criterion then you should be able to achieve your objective.

```
'where={"$or":[{"wins":{"$gt":150}},{"wins":{"$lt":5}}]}'
```

**Compound Query Example**

The $or clause is the example used on the Parse Website under compound queries. The code above can be transposed to your use-case and applied using the encoded url method specified previously.

[image: compound-query]

**Nota Bene**

Notice that the example below shows retrieval of multiple related objects (using $inQuery). There are limits regarding how many inner objects may be retrieved. I noticed that this is basically the equivalence of what you are doing in code so hopefully the extrapolation would be relatively straight-forward using this sample.

[image: multiple-objects]

**Caution**

Please note this word of caution from Parse on when to use the REST-API.

[image: rest-api-caution]